# How to use specific symbol of SVG in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, symbols

I've download google SVG file and droped to xcode and I can see

[image]

The name of the reasource is `search` and I used in `UIButton` as  `button.setImage(UIImage(named: "search")!, for: .normal)` which works fine.

But I want to use `Medium-Light` image. I am not sure how could I use, I tried `search-medium-light` but It crashes. Is there a way to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different sizes and scales form part of the [`UIImage.SymbolConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/symbolconfiguration), which you should use when creating the image:

```swift
let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .light)
    .applying(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .medium))
let image = UIImage(named: "search", in: nil, with: configuration)
```